# How do I create an array of multiple values extracted from the rows and columns of excel

Tags: python, arrays

```
import xlrd

fw = 'C://Users/MM/Desktop/'

test=[]

wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(fw + 'assignment.xls')
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

for a in range(2,sh1.nrows):    
    for b in range(0,sh1.ncols):
        test.append(sh1.cell(a,b).value)
print(test)
```

I have this code, but it is not doing what I want it to do. 
The output I am getting is

```
[0,200,clothes,1,300,shoes,2,900,food]
```

But, instead I want to have:

```
[0,200,clothes],[1,300,shoes],[2,900,food]
```

I can't think of anyway to get that. 
What I want is the code to read each row's data from every column and put it in the form I have above. "0" is column 0, "200" is in column 1, "clothes" is in column 2. I am sure this is know from the code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new list for each row on every row iteration:

```
test = []

for a in range(2, sh1.nrows):
    row = []
    for b in range(0, sh1.ncols):
        row.append(sh1.cell(a, b).value)
    test.append(row)

print(test)
```

Comment: That does it ! Thanks

Comment: How can I use those values from those arrays individually for something ?

Comment: @MasterMind You can do `print(test[0][2])` to print 3rd column from the first row for example.

Comment: With the original problem, I had I am not getting those words in the array. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not really getting. Which "those words" in which array?

Comment: clothes, shoes and food. Also, I want to individually use them in formulas, such for example 200,300, and 900 and add them.

Comment: Can you please help me with question on the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797433/make-the-percentages-equal-using-a-formula-function-in-python-for-the-values-pul

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for things like this.

```
test = [[sh1.cell(a,b).value for b in range(0, sh1.ncols)] for a in range(2, sh1.nrows)]
```